# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker when I try to create a post

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying create a post, I'm not quite sure why I get this error. An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker, if someone could shed some light for me

This is the code in my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(NewPostModel model)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    var post = BuildPost(model, user);
    await PostService.Instance.Add(post);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Post", new { id = post.Id });
}

private Post BuildPost(NewPostModel post, ApplicationUser user)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var forum = ForumServices.Instance.GetById(post.ForumId);

    return new Post
    {
        Title = post.Title,
        Content = post.Content,
        Created = now,
        Forum = forum,
        User = user,
        IsArchived = false
    };
}
```

A here is my code in the PostService

```
public async Task Add(Post post)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        context.Posts.Add(post);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

When I debug, the controller gets the model and the user, however when it gets to the `await PostService.Instance.Add(post);` it goes to the PostService then comes back to the await line in the controller then I get the error. I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception because the `forum` and `user` property values belong to another Entity Framework context.

When you create your new `Post` you assign the `Forum` property to a forum instance. That instance came from `ForumServices.Instance.GetById` and is associated to a context. Then you add the `Post` object to another context, the `forum` instance is now associated to 2 contexts which is not possible.

To fix this, you can change the architecture to use a single EF context per request. It looks like you use a singleton (`ForumServices.Instance`) if you use .net core, you should have a look at how dependency injection works and use the `AddScoped` method to have a single EF context for the whole life time of the request. This is the solution I highly recommend.

If it is not possible to change the way context are created you can assign Id instead of full object

```
return new Post
{
    Title = post.Title,
    Content = post.Content,
    Created = now,
    ForumId = forum.ForumId,
    UserId = user.UserId,
    IsArchived = false
};
```

If it is still not possible you can return untracked entities. You can do this by using the `AsNoTracking` method or by using the `QueryTrackingBehavior` property of the context

```
context.Forums.AsNoTracking().First(f => f.ForumId == forumId); 
// or
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, I did as suggested by adding a **ForumId** and **UserId** to the models

```
return new Post
{
     Title = post.Title,
     Content = post.Content,
     Created = now,
     ForumId = post.ForumId,
     UserId = user.Id,
     IsArchived = false
};
```